# Is there an implementation of log4net.ILog that is backed by a Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger?

Tags: log4net

I have an app that uses the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging package(s) for logging. I need to interact with another library that requires me to pass in a `log4net.ILog` in some places (please no discussion of the merits of that kind of library API - I can't change it).

What would be the strategy have a "wrapper" `log4net.ILog` impl that uses an `ILogger` under the covers? Is there any such implementation out there? Looking at the interface of `log4net.ILog` it looks somewhat involved to write from scratch, for example implementing the log4net ILogger interface is also required.

This really feels like reinventing the wheel; I've tried searching, but everything I find seems to be going in the other direction - using  log4net as the backing impl for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging API.

Comment: Anyone of the close voters care to comment as to why they think this is off-topic? It's not asking for any opinion, just an impl of a possibly common need.

Comment: "Is there an implementation out there" is pretty clearly "asking for an off-site resource". Link-only answers aren't allowed either, so we can't post "yes, and it's over there". If you actually wanted to get an implementation as an answer (as in, all of the code) that wasn't what I got out of it.

Comment: Regardless this question is closed, maybe you can take the open source code from here https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore and implement your own version exposing the ILog private field as a Property or something.